# Polymeric sand loosens when slightly wet, is that normal, and what's the best way to cover it?

Tags: water, waterproofing, patio, mortar, pavers

I laid polymeric sand on a patio (made of paver blocks), and it looked great.  I followed the instructions, and it didn't rain within about a week of my laying it.  It ended up perfect, and it's hard as a rock...when it's dry outside.

When it rains, or I try to wash it off with a hose (from mud getting on it), it gets incredibly soft, and will peel up easily.  I noticed the problem about a month after I laid it, and we had a rain.  Mud washed onto it, but there wasn't much water.  I sprayed the mud down, and got a leaf blower (on the lowest setting), and blew the water/mud off.  I noticed a decent amount of the polymeric sand was also peeling off with the mud.  Now it looks terrible, but when it dries, it's hard as a rock again, and none of it will budge.  Even the flakes that are mostly peeled off are hard as a rock, and won't break off easily.

Is this normal?  Did I do something terribly wrong.  No matter what, there's no chance of me ever using this stuff again.  It looks great, but it was terribly expensive, and now has lasted me about a month.

So, secondary question, is there a way to cover this?  I'm not even against the idea of getting mortar and putting a thin layer of mortar over this.  I'm not sure a thin layer of mortar is a good idea, but I don't want this stuff washing everywhere and ruining other things when it's wet.

Comment: i did a quick google search .... you apparently forgot to install paver blocks .... the sand is supposed to fill the gaps between pavers

Comment: haha, I wish that was the case.  It is between paver blocks.  I guess I should have mentioned that, but I figured it was a given.

Comment: it is not a given unless it is specifically stated .... people do all sorts of weird stuff .... lol .... you need to say that you used polymeric sand as filler between pavers .... right now you are saying that you laid it on top of pavers

Comment: how wide are the gaps between the pavers?

Comment: The bag of sand said the gaps could go as wide as 2 inches.  My gaps around about 1/2 inch in most places, and about 3/4 inch in a few places.